# Specify xmax in axhline based on the x-values

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Consider the example below:

```py
pca=[0.7,0.2,0.08,0.02]
cumsum=np.cumsum(pca)
ax = sns.lineplot(x =np.arange(len(pca)),y=cumsum)

x_hline = np.argwhere(cumsum>=0.95)[0] # = 3
#ISSUE: Missing some code here to calculate x_hline correctly#
#
#
#

ax.axhline(y=0.95,xmin=0,xmax=x_hline)
```

I want to draw an horizontal line which starts a 0 and ends when we have reached  x-value by `x_hline`. Since `xmax` is the specified ratio of the width of the figure i.e between 0 and 1, it is not possible to parse `x_hline`. I tried to do

```py
x_hline= np.argwhere(cumsum>=0.95)[0] #Assume it is "3"
x_hline= (1-1/x_hline)
```

and it works (most of the time, okay), but it is not really robust. Is there a way to get the exact ratio of the width, where an element/xtick is according to the ratio of the width (it this case, at what ratio-point is the third element plotted?)

EDIT:
Rewritten the question

Comment: You really need `ax.hlines`. You might want to add some stand-alone code and data (as a continuous code block, not separated inside the explanations) to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have tried re-writing the question to make it more clear now

Comment: Well, you really need `ax.hlines` which works in data coordinates. Use a very low left value; everything that is too low will be cut away by the `xlim`.  You can call `x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim()` before drawing the line, and `ax.set_xlim(x0,x1)` afterwards to reset those limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get more control in this fashion:

```
ax.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 'k-',linewidth=4)
```

where x1=0, x2=x_hline, y1=y2=0.95

Comment: Aah... Of course! I might've locked in too much on the "function made for it"

Comment: Happy to help. If you found the solution helpful and it resolved your problem, you want to check the green mark. This will help keep the focus on unresolved questions.